# How do I create a scoring system in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone show me an example of a system where when you answer a question right it gives you one point and at the end of the quiz it gives me a total of how much I got right?

This is the code I have so far:

```
def QuestionSet1():
print("Challenge level 1 has being selected.")
print("Can you translate these words into french?")
a=input('Q1. Hello! :')
if 'Bonjour' in a: 
    score = score + 1
    print('Correct!')
elif 'bonjour'in a:
    score = score + 1
    print('Correct!')
else:
    print('Wrong! '+'Its Bonjour')
    print('You have finished and scored', score, 'out of 10')
```

Comment: Yes I tried but it kept coming up with errors.

Comment: I just want an example of a simple one.

Comment: This is rather too broad for Stack Overflow. Can you show us the code you have so far - how are you storing questions? Do you have a loop to show all questions? How are you taking your input inside that loop? How are you deciding whether an answer is correct or not? Is this a console program?

Comment: I just want to know how to add all of them up.

Comment: In Python, doesn't everything under the `def` line need to be indented? I don't write Python though, so...

Comment: It looks like your prompts talk about words (plural) but you are only getting one answer. Can you modify your code to store a word list? I imagine you would need an array of some kind.

Comment: Btw no need for a `+` in your second last print statement. And watch out, an empty sequence is also `in` any string (`"" in "hi"` - returns True).   Better might be `a.lower() in ("bonjour",)`. Then you also got the option to catch multiple possible right solutions at once: `a.lower() in ("bonjour","bonjour!")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def QuestionSet1():
    print("Challenge level 1 has being selected.")
    print("Can you translate these words into french?")
    a=input('Q1. Hello! :')
    score = 0
    if 'bonjour' in a.lower(): 
        score = score + 1
        print('Correct!')
    else:
        print('Wrong! '+'Its Bonjour')
        print('You have finished and scored', score, 'out of 10')
```

You would need make a reference to `score` before you give it a value.

You can also remove one of the if statements by converting the input to lower case and checking the lower case value.